# PHP Eclipse live file editing or FTP

Tags: php, eclipse, ftp

I am assigned on a project where I need to code an entire website. But I want to work on realtime environment. My favourite IDE is PHP Eclipse and I want to know is their any plugin for it where I edit any files and the changes will be uploaded directly on the live server?

I want to work on realtime, is it really possible on PHP Eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use [Remote Systems Explorer](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/gettingstarted/g1installing.html) for that. Simply install and browse remote FTP repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Remote System Explorer.

It will allow you to edit files over SSH.  I believe you can do FTP as well, but I don't recommend FTP for security reasons.